# How to display the multiple details in a single listbox in asp

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net, listview

I searched over Google i didn't get my Requirement
My Output Like
[image]
Now I want to Display Like 
[image]
How to do?
I have Two tables Like **SystemUsers** and **UserSoftware** Details

**SystemUsers** table Having **SystemUserName,DepartmentId,SystemId,SystemUserId**
**UserSoftwareDetails** Having **UserSwDetId,SystemUserId,Software,SoftwareKey**

My Aspx Coding Like

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"  GroupItemCount="3" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"
    ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </table> 
   </LayoutTemplate> 
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
     </tr> 
 </GroupTemplate> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td >
            <table cellpadding="2" frame="box"  cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 300px; height: 150px; ">
                              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>User Name:</b> <span ><%# Eval("SystemUserName") %></span><br />
                        <b>Software: </b><span ><%# Eval("Software") %></span> <br />
                         <b>Software Key: </b><span ><%#Eval("SoftwareKey")%></span> <br />
                   </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

How to Get this type of output?,,
thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your ASPX page :

```
 <asp:ListView ID="Business" runat="server" OnPagePropertiesChanging="OnPagePropertiesChanging">
 <ItemTemplate>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
        <tr> 
          <td>
         Username : 

            </td>                                                           
         <td>             
        <%# Eval("SystemUserName")%>
          </td> 
        </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>
     Software : 
     </td>
         <td>
        <%# Eval("UserSoftwareDetails")%></b>                                      
         </td>                                                        
    </tr>                             

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

// If you need Paging then add DataPager Ovehere 
 <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="Business" PageSize="9">
        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="false"    ShowPreviousPageButton="true"
                        ShowNextPageButton="false" />
                    <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link" />
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="false"
      </DataPager>
```

Code BEHIND :

```
    Bind your ListView (Write Stored Procedure To Display Records) 
         private void BindListView()
          {
             // Write your Code 
          }

          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             BindListView();
            }



   and if you are doing Paging 
    protected void OnPagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);

        this.BindListView();
    }
```

Comment: indicate or explain what you have changed, what was wrong with him

Comment: @Neethu Soman--> that Coding is Correct ButOne user having 2 or more SOftware then how it will display ?

Comment: Neethu when i saw this post it was not updated, updation was done later on.So i was not aware what he did.My mistake :)